# Prevent resetting termset connection taxonomy field content type hub

Tags: sharepoint-server, taxonomy, content-type-hub

We have a setup where we have a content type hub with a range of taxonomy fields. Ideally we want to assign/connect the taxonomy fields on the destination site collections to individual domain specific term sets which contain a specific filtered subset of terms from the farm-wide terms collection.

But, the issue here is that every time we replicate a new version of our content types, this connection on local level is overwritten by the connection at content type hub level. The taxonomy fields at content type level are assigned to term store and term set `Guid.Empty`. The effect is that also the field at site collection level becomes `Guid.Empty`.

How can we prevent this? Or what would be a better setup to:

1. Have a farm wide data model and a enterprise wide collection of
   taxonomies
2. But have site collection (domain) specific filtered taxonomies

Maybe we should drop the OOTB content type hub and build our own taxonomy fields provisioning?

Comment: We've had the same problem. Writing some script that should run before and after the publishing in the hub (and after timer jobs run) to reset the fields was our quick fix. But to me this is a major limitation of the content type hub

Comment: Thanks, so essentially you are saying, capture all taxonomy field connections upfront ("backup") and after replication, just "restore" them. Sounds feasible enough. Any chance you know how we can get a notification when the replication process is finished? This takes quite some time in a big farm.

Comment: Yeah, thats what we did. You can always run the two timer jobs yourself (hub and subscriber), that way you can see the process and when it finishes